# How to insert a line break without a br tag

Tags: html, css

How do i insert a line break in a single paragraph, without a `<br>` tag ? see below:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use a <br> tag?

Comment: in html?  or what language? css there is plenty too.  use css.  Anything will work, apply a style attribute to the html tag `style="height:10px"` to a block elem, or `style="padding:10px"` an inline elem for example.

Please revise your question completely, adding detail.

Comment: I wanted a semantic way !

Answer (score 0):

You can just press enter inside of a `<pre>`tag`</pre>` using HTML.

In CSS you can use `white-space:pre` or `white-space:pre-wrap`

In programming you use a newline `\n`

> **JS Bin Example:** http://jsbin.com/simeri/edit?html,output

```
<p style='white-space:pre-wrap;text-align:center;font:bold 130% sans-serif'>
    Google Fonts. Hundreds of free, open-source fonts optimized for the web...
    Search or browse hundreds of font families, then add the ones you like to your ..
</p>
```

Comment: did't think of this .. thanks ! but not sure this is the most semantic way !

Comment: ````<pre>```` would be the most semantic way, but Google would most likely be using the ````white-space:pre-wrap```` CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css word-wrap property like below:

```
  width: 200px; /*width of area after you want line break*/
  word-wrap: break-word; /*break down the paragraph/text*/
```

or use \n dynamically into your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<p style=' white-space: pre-line;text-align:center;font:bold 100% sans-serif'>
Google Fonts. Hundreds of free, open-source fonts optimized for the web...
  Search or browse hundreds of font families, then add the ones you like to your ..
</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use &nbsp..?

```
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

This is what works within Canvas LMS...